# how to compile boost_thread for android NDK?

Tags: gcc, boost, android-ndk, boost-thread

I have a neeed to create threads and I am preferring to use boost threads! Firstly is this possible for android-ndk ?
If so, then I started to include boost_thread sources in my project.
I referred some stackoverflow posts where I found the need to define these
BOOST_THREAD_BUILD_LIB, BOOST_REGEX_NO_LIB
Defining these prevented me from getting the link error asking for "libboost_thread_*.lib"

However now its asking for "libboost_data_time_*.lib"
What should I define now ? And what else will I need to do to finally get the source compiled in my project. 
Know that I can't use boost.build as it won't suit my need (compiler varies).

Answer (score 0):

You can define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB to turn on all the BOOST_*_NO_LIB options.